# geofield types failed to add with commerce services

Tags: commerce, services, location

I have added field of type Geofield  that failed to save through services despite working well with node and user modules

It returns that error **400 : Invalid field_geoloc value given** I am using the same field structure for node and user.

I did some debugging and found that the error comes from file **commerce_services.module** line 1406
that piece of code

`if (count(array_diff_key($value, $field_info['columns'])) > 0) { return services_error(t('Invalid @field value given', array('@field' => $field_name)), 400);
    }`
here is the field structure

```
"field_geoloc": {
    "und": [
        {
            "geom": {
                "lat": "22",
                "lon": "22"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Please help me fix it or guide to fix it.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think a value of `22` is valid for either coordinate. This answer may be useful: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/146546/10645 - remember the values you send up are dependant on the form widget you have selected for the field in Drupal. I'd recommend adding this line above line 1406: `watchdog('commerce_services', '<pre>' . print_r($field_info['columns'], true) . '</pre>');` - that way you can see what it is expecting.

Comment: that values are accepted for user and node modules, I think it needs complete field data unlike node and user modules does here is the output of the watchdog at commerce services http://pastebin.com/rkfpyKLn

Comment: Have you checked the issue queue?

Comment: I have checked and created an issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to send computed values via the **geofield** module api itself by Implementing the **hook_request_parsed_alter** like:

```
function my_module_request_parsed_alter(&$data, $controller) {
switch ($controller['callback']) {
case 'commerce_services_product_create':
case 'commerce_services_product_update':

  if (isset($data['field_geoloc'])) {
    $data["field_geoloc"] = geofield_compute_values($data['field_geoloc']['und'][0]['geom']);
  }
}
```

But I still wonder why not working by default as node create request